# « Au plaisir de vous entendre »: Est-ce approprié pour un email formel et poli ?

Tags: expressions, politesse, email

Est-il approprié de dire:

**"Au plaisir de vous entendre."**

à la fin d'un email **formel** et d'un email **poli**? Ou existe-t-il une meilleure alternative?

Nous attendons la réponse du destinataire et voulons mentionner qu'**il est notre responsable**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Au plaisir de  » est une forme standard ; ce qui ne convient pas c'est le choix particulier de complément. Voici un choix courant de compléments ;

- vous revoir
- voir
- lire

Évidemment, si la réception de l'e-mail doit donner suite à une conversation téléphonique ces compléments ne seront pas ce qu'il faut ; « entendre » ne le sera pas non plus parce que c'est un verbe trop général. Quelque chose comme « Au plaisir de notre conversation prochaine » conviendrait à mon avis.

La politesse va de soi dans une communication formelle, elle est forcée par le formalisme ; donc on ne dit pas « formel et poli » mais on peut dire « formel et courtois » ce qui signifie que quelque chose de plus que la politesse de rigueur fait partie des formules, quelque chose qui marque plus de considération pour les personnes à qui l'on s'adresse.

Pour un e-mail ces formules sont jugées être [informelles](https://references.lesoir.be/article/quelle-formule-de-politesse-devez-vous-utiliser-dans-vos-e-mails/). Il y a plus formel, mais tout dépend du degré de familiarité qui existe dans la relation avec la personne à qui on écrit. Si on attend un retour écrit on utilise « lire » ; si on a prévu de revoir/voir (rencontrer) la personne en question on utilise « revoir/voir ».

Pour un e-mail formel une autre formule sera nécessaire, telle que par exemple l'une des deux suivantes, aussi extraites de la référence ci-dessus ;

- Meilleures salutations,
- Cordiales salutations,

Une formule très formelle sera la suivante, mais il y en a d'autre ;

- Dans l'attente de vous lire je/nous vous prie/prions d'agréer Monsieur/Madame le/la [fonction de la personne responsable] mes/nos sincères salutations,

Il n'est pas habituel, sauf pour les organismes et organisations d'utiliser la première personne du pluriel dans les formules de la fin, mais je crois qu'il n'y a pas de problème pour les particuliers si dans le corps du texte il est clair que les déclarations sont faites au nom de deux ou plusieurs personnes (c'est l'utilisation de cette première personne du pluriel dans le corps de texte qui rend cela clair).

Si le titre de fonction est long, il n'est pas conseillé de l'utiliser en entier : il vaut mieux l'abréger ; par exemple, au lieu de « Madame la directrices du cabinet des litiges des affaires locales », il vaut beaucoup mieux écrire tout simplement « madame la directrice ».

Des variantes courantes sont « l'expression de mes/nos sincères salutations », l'expression de mes/nos cordiales salutations ».

Comment: Je ne dirais jamais « Au plaisir de notre conversation prochaine » et je doute que beaucoup de francophones le disent ! Ça ne sonne absolument pas français.

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous Si l'on devait se limiter à seulement ce qui a été dit on n'aurait jamais rien dit et il n'y aurait pas de langue en existence ; ce sont ici les principes mêmes de votre conception de l'évolution du langage qui sont en action pour construire la langue ;  mon invention ne relève cependant  de ces principes qu'en un  degré très modeste, qui touche essentiellement à l'utilisation. Ce n'est pas une raison parce que cela n'a jamais été dit que ça ne dit pas quelque chose. (1/3)

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous Ce qui compte c'est la grammaire de l'énonciation et la logique des choses mises en relation. Je crois qu'ici il n'y a de  problème ni de grammaire ni de logique de base. Je pense que dans les limites que je pose on  doit absolument laisser aux gens leur pleine initiative d'improviser ; c'est un principe fondamental dans ma compréhension de ce qui consiste en l'utilisation d'une langue. (2/3)

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous  Dites-moi maintenant que vous n'aimez pas (trop) l'idée que l'on puisse envisager systématiquement un certain plaisir dans une  conversation à venir puisque c'est quelque chose qui peut impliquer le plus souvent de l'imprévu, une routine sans intérêt, un affrontement, etc., et je comprendrai mieux ; oui, en effet, cette formule peut ne pas être des plus appropriées dans certains cas. (3/3)

Answer (score 0):

Par définition, on n'entend personne dans un email, on ne fait que lire.

Donc, à moins que la personne projette d'entendre (et de seulement entendre sans voir) la personne prochainement, cette phrase n'a aucun sens.

Normalement: Au plaisir de vous lire (si par email),

ou Au plaisir de vous voir (une entrevue, une rencontre).